# Posting to database from dropdown menu Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.1

I have created a dropdown menu that is pulling Cities and Countries from two database tables (named citie and country).

I am using the following collection_select tag:

```
    <section class="field">     
      <%= f.label :city %>
      <%= f.collection_select(:id, Citie.all, :id, :city) %>
    </section>
```

But when I submit my form nothing is being posted into my jobs table (the form is to generate a new job).

I have searched  to find a solution for this and am sure I am just missing a small part but can't seem to figure out what it is and why it's not working.

Any advice and a solution would be much appreciated! Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not terribly familliar with collection_select but shouldn't you give the association name as the first argument? e.g.

```
<%= f.collection_select(:city, Citie.all, :id, :city) %>
```

Comment: Hi Peter, this has worked great but I am only passing the object id into my job table - how would I pass the actual object name? thanks

Comment: That would be the third argument, that determines what attribute is listed as the VALUE of the option tags. So to list the name instead of the id:

    <%= f.collection_select(:city, Citie.all, :name, :city) %>

Just replace :name with whatever attribute you want to send (:city maybe?)